# Optimal selection of k in K-NN

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameter-tuning, k-nn

I am currently reviewing some concepts related to Machine Learning, and I started to wonder about the hyperparameter selection of K-NN classifier.

Suppose you need to solve a classification task with a number of classes equal to M: I was thinking that the best choice for the parameter K of our classifier should be for K > M.

In this way, we are avoiding all the pathological cases in which a sample may be in the middle of all the M classes and then have a tie. For instance, consider the following example in which we have M=3 and each geometrical shape represents a class:

[image]

Assume that K<=M: for sure you will have a tie for a sample in the middle of samples 1, 2 and 3. This tie could be avoided if K > M.

Clearly this is just a toy example, but I think it is sufficient to illustrate my thoughts. I have tried to look for an answer but I wasn't able to find any resource mentioning this, am I wrong in some way or this reasoning may be sound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea isn't wrong, however in k-NN there **always** might be a case where you have the same number of votes for 2 or more classes (e.g. you have $k=6$ and you have 3 samples of one class vs 3 of another). With your solution you are just overcoming one very small case of ties and the $k$ that you choose might **not be the optimal** $k$ for classification, which is your primary objective (i.e. you might hurt your classification performance with a sub-optimal $k$ so that you don't get one type of ties).

Because there are also other times of ties, you always need to have a **tiebreaker** condition. I have seen a lot of strategies for this, like reducing $k$ by one until you break the tie, selecting the class with the minimum distance, selecting the class with the fewest samples overall, etc.

Since you already have such a condition, you could also handle your situation, without selecting a sub-optimal $k$.

Answer (score 3):

As I was playing with this problem, [Djib just wrote an answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/87465/64377) which is certainly better than whatever I could have come up with. To illustrate Djib's point, here is a small demonstration that as soon as there are more than 2 classes there's no value of $k$ which guarantees the absence of tie (except if $k=1$ of course).

By definition we have $k=|c_1| + |c_2| + ... + |c_n|$, where $|c_i|$ is the number of instances for the class $c_i$. Let $|c_1|\geq |c_2|$ be the number of instances for the top two classes. A tie is when (at least) the top two classes have the same number of instances: $|c_1| = |c_2|$ (it doesn't matter when there is a tie which is not at the top).

It's easy to prove that for any integer $k>1$, there are always two integers $a\geq b\geq 0$ such that $2a+b=k$: if $k$ is even, pick $a=k/2$ and $b=0$. If $k$ is odd, pick the integer part of $k/2$ as $a$ and $b=1$.

So for any $k$ it's always possible to find $a\geq b\geq 0$ such that $|c_1|=|c_2|=a$ and $|c_3|=b$. Therefore it's always possible to have a tie at the top of the ranking of at least 3 classes in $k$-NN, whatever the value of $k$.

Example with 3 classes and $k=4$ (note that $k>M$): a tie happens when $|c_1|=|c_2|=2$ and $|c_3|=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was really helpful. I accepted Djib2011 answer just because it came before and it was equally interesting. Thank you again for your time!

Answer (score 1):

To add a couple of references, to the already good answers, on the problem of selecting the optimum $k$ for $k-NN$.

1. [How to find the optimal value of K in KNN?](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-find-the-optimal-value-of-k-in-knn-35d936e554eb)

> **Then how to select the optimal K value?**
>
> - There are no pre-defined statistical methods to find the most favorable value of K.
> - Initialize a random K value and start computing.
> - Choosing a small value of K leads to unstable decision boundaries.
> - The substantial K value is better for classification as it leads to smoothening the decision boundaries.
> - Derive a plot between error rate and K denoting values in a defined range. Then choose the K value as having a minimum error rate.

2. [K-nearest neighbors algorithm, Parameter selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm#Parameter_selection)

> The best choice of k depends upon the data; generally, larger values
> of k reduces effect of the noise on the classification, but make
> boundaries between classes less distinct. A good k can be selected by
> various heuristic techniques (see hyperparameter optimization). The
> special case where the class is predicted to be the class of the
> closest training sample (i.e. when k = 1) is called the nearest
> neighbor algorithm.
>
> The accuracy of the k-NN algorithm can be severely degraded by the
> presence of noisy or irrelevant features, or if the feature scales are
> not consistent with their importance. Much research effort has been
> put into selecting or scaling features to improve classification. A
> particularly popular[citation needed] approach is the use of
> evolutionary algorithms to optimize feature scaling. Another popular
> approach is to scale features by the mutual information of the
> training data with the training classes.
>
> In binary (two class) classification problems, it is helpful to choose
> k to be an odd number as this avoids tied votes. One popular way of
> choosing the empirically optimal k in this setting is via bootstrap
> method.

3. [Optimal choice of k for k-nearest neighbor regression](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.05495)

> The k-nearest neighbor algorithm (k-NN) is a widely used
> non-parametric method for classification and regression. We study the
> mean squared error of the k-NN estimator when k is chosen by
> leave-one-out cross-validation (LOOCV). Although it was known that
> this choice of k is asymptotically consistent, it was not known
> previously that it is an optimal k. We show, with high probability,
> the mean squared error of this estimator is close to the minimum mean
> squared error using the k-NN estimate, where the minimum is over all
> choices of k.